# Mutliple button same event with array parameter

Tags: ios, event-handling, uibutton

I have for example 10 buttons. All 10 buttons need to do the same but with other variables (1 button type, one string type etc..).

Can i send a single dimension array as parameter at a button event?

I use this code:

```
[btn_gv_tl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(click_gv_tl1) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

I have this code 10 times under eacht other with 10 different methods. I would like to call the same method with a array of parameters.

is that possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use storyboard? In storyboard, you would be able to do a single IBAction from all buttons and pass the sender (UIButton) as an attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little code for illustration

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *btn_gv_tl1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btn_gv_tl1.frame = CGRectMake( 10, 10, 100, 43 );
    [btn_gv_tl1 setTitle:@"tl1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_gv_tl1 addTarget:self action:@selector(click_gv_tl1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:btn_gv_tl1];
}

- (void)click_gv_tl1
{
    NSLog( @"some button was pressed" );
}

- (void)click_gv_tl1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog( @"%@", sender.titleLabel.text );
}
```

The only difference between calling the first method that prints "some button was pressed" and calling the second method is the colon in the @selector.  In other words use `@selector(click_gv_tl1)` to call the first method, or use `@selector(click_gv_tl1:)` to call the second method.

In the second method, the argument is the button object for the button that was pressed.  You can check the button title to see which button was pressed, or you can give each button a `tag`, and determine which button was pressed based on `sender.tag`.

Comment: Thanks, got that working. The only problem is the setTitle. I want to use it to set the state.

I use this code:

[arrayButton setTitle:@"on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString *x = [[arrayButton titleLabel] text];

But if i debug, the x has the value of "Button" instead of "on"

Comment: That's strange.  I tried a few things (like disabling the button) in an attempt to duplicate that problem, but was unsuccessful.  I always got a value of "on".  Did you try an `NSLog( @"%@", x );` after the second line.  Maybe it's just the debugger.

Comment: Than this is the output: 2014-03-28 14:13:18.413 HoCo[850:60b] Button

Comment: LOL, makes no sense. The two lines of code in your first comment can't possibly generate that output.  Can you add a section to the original post that has the code from the creation of the button to the NSLog.  I'll put it in my test project and see if I can duplicate.  P.S. on the simulator or device, what shows up as the button text?

Comment: I have this code: http://www.sourcepod.com/ojfepg06-23889
The button is a image on a background image so text is "Button" i see now. but because the button is a background image with on top another image i don't see any text.

Comment: Ah ok, that's why I mentioned `tags` in my answer. Every class derived from UIView, including UIButton, has a property called `tag`. The tag is just an integer that you can set to any value that you want. So I suggest something like `arrayButton.tag = 101;  int x = arrayButton.tag;` to positively identify each button

Comment: Ok, but i use the tag to give the button an id (first button gets tag 0, the second tag 1 etc..)

Comment: I think i got it... deleted the button text in the storyboard and now it updates to "on".. Thanks!